# Your privacy settings blocked access to your location

Tags: windows, privacy, windows-11, notifications

On a computer with Windows 11, about every week, I get a notification saying, "Your privacy settings blocked access to your location", and "If you want to change these settings, go to Settings"

The computer I am talking about is new and I think it started about a month after I got it.

The notification happens when I am not using the computer.

All I have installed is Godot, Ardunio, VS code, OBS studio and Shotcut.

I have my location blocked, but I want to know why I keep getting the notification.

Comment: A quick google search leads me to believe that this might be a more common question that expected --[Microsoft Support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-can-the-notification-your-privacy-settings/0816688b-d83a-454f-a656-bbb8a11078c7), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/rfrq57/your_privacy_settings_blocked_access_to_your/)-- and one without an immediately obvious answer. I'm curious to see if anyone knows how to view the offending app from an audit log or something.

Comment: I posted an amendment to my answer as to why these notifications come up. I have a number of apps that cause this and I see the notifications. I have not disabled them to continue to see all the apps that cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have my location blocked, but I want to know why I keep getting the
> notification.

These notifications come up if an App (driver updates, Lenovo Vantage, Mapping apps and other like apps) wish to use your location and your Privacy settings block that, then you will get the notification coming up.

Windows 11 have used Location and Privacy notifications since it came out last July 2021

Just turn the Notification OFF is you do not want it.

Go to Settings, Notifications and disable (uncheck) Privacy Notifications.

[image: Privacy Notifications]

Comment: Also to be sure I understand you, there are apps (eg. Lenovo Vantage ) that do not spawn processes locking for location. So when you use the generic term process, Location awareness is often done by the App itself.

Answer (score 0):

The app asking for location was dell supportassist.

What I did was uncheck the block location access and supportassist was the only one that got checked by default.

[image]